# Reassigning std::bind using auto: which compiler gets it right?

Tags: c++, c++11

MSVC compiles the following code, while GCC and Clang don't.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Class
{
    public:
        void display() { std::cout << "display" << std::endl; }
        void store() { std::cout << "store" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Class instance;
    // std::function<void(void)> f; // this will work
    auto f = std::bind(&Class::display, instance);
    f();
    f = std::bind(&Class::store, instance);
    f();
}
```

<sub>[Godbolt conformance view](https://godbolt.org/z/3qdGx6jE9)</sub>

It seems that GCC and Clang have the copy assignment operator deleted.

Which compilers get it more correct from a standard point of view?

Comment: Nothing explicitly allows or disallows this to be accepted or rejected for `std::bind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the exact wording in the standard, but the compiler error together with cppreference give a pretty good idea of what is happening:

According to the standard, the implicitly defined copy constructor is deleted, if the class implements a move constructor. If a default copy constructor exists, it will not be deleted https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor.

The return type of std::bind is an unspecified copy-constructible type (if all arguments are copy-constructible) and move-constructible otherwise. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind.

So I suppose all compilers are correct in having freedom for the unspecified part of the standard.

On a side note, I would capture the instance in a lambda instead of using `std::bind`.

Comment: Oh, I see ... this copy-constructibleness concerns the `std::bind` class, not my class. Therefore I can't influcence this.

Comment: Yes exactly! I would use a lambda, so your code is portable. `std::function` uses type erasure techniques that usually come at some extra runtime cost due to some hidden dynamic dispatch calls. https://godbolt.org/z/6q8a4d9x5.

Comment: Thanks. I know about lambdas and I'll probably rewrite the affected piece of code. But I first wanted to fully understand it and the consequences. (And potentially file a bug at Microsoft if their compiler weren't standard compliant, but that's ruled out now).

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the binding type is unspecified, outside of the following: you can call it with a certain set of parameters based on the placeholders, it's move constructible/destructible, and if all of the bound parameters are copyable, then it too will be copy constructible.

That's it. There is no requirement that the type is copy-assignable. It is therefore... unspecified. So *all of them* are right.

And if you want your code to be portable, you shouldn't rely on unspecified behavior.